# Limit Bootstrap UI's width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website that uses a Bootstrap UI, that can be found [here](http://hiimstring3.hpage.com/). At the moment, the UI's width is not limited, and is thus, going to the ends of the page. I was wondering how I would limit the width of the UI. Now, I'm not too experienced in CSS or web development in general, so please excuse my ignorance. Below is how I thought I would do it, using CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.custom {
width: (width)px !important;
  }
</style>
```

I then tried to place the '.custom' on the end of the "container" div to be < div class="container.custom" >. Now I know this is wrong, as it isn't working, so I was wondering how I could fix this, and implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to declare to classes for a div, you have to put it this way `<div class="class1 class2">`, without the dot (".").

Please don't use frames to realize a website, this is horrible. Also `!important` should only be used if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I did what you said, and it works perfectly. What do you mean by, 'don't use frames to realize a website'?

Comment: have a look here: http://www.mattheerema.com/web-tech-design/2005/09/exactly-why-are-frames-bad/

Comment: Ah right, well this website is just for a class assignment, and the teacher stated that he was fine with our websites using a frameset. As a result of this, I'm not too fussed about search ranking, and what not, however, if I were to make a website, outside of school, then I wouldn't use a frameset. Thanks for the help and the article, quite informative.

Answer (score 1):

When adding multiple classes to an element you separate them with a space.

```
<div class="container custom">
```